# JAVA error at Main.<init>()

Tags: java

**In my class I call the main method called "check".
This method works as a login and when the data is correct calls the method "mainAdmin".

In my method "mainAdmin" of my class "main" I have a menu option that should return to the login method

The code itself compiles but when I run it I get this error:

```
at Login.<init>(Login.java:6) 
at Main.<init>(Main.java:7)
```

Please help me.**

```
public class Login{

              //this is my class called login

              Main main=new Main();

              public void check(){

              //This method is a login where it compares data established

              }



              public void loginGen(){

               //this method is other login where it compares data whith an array

              }
}
```

```
public class Main{

     //this is other class called main
                Login login=new Login();

                public void mainAdmin(){
                //this method works like a main

                }

}
```

Comment: You're missing the most important text from your error message. Please show all of it.

Comment: So the login class creates an instance of the main class which creates an instance of the login class which creates an instance of the main class which .... Guessing you might run into a stack overflow error due to infinite recursion?

Comment: stackoverflow error!!!!!